# XPS 13 brcmfmac BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, dell-xps, broadcom

First, I'd just like to point out that this question has also been asked [at the Arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230349) without success. Further context might be obtained from that short thread. I'm posting here to broaden the audience a bit, as it seems not to be specific to Arch (based on another XPS user's response).

I have a Dell XPS 13 (9350) laptop. On a fairly regular basis (around once or twice a day, though at different times and not always after an obvious event e.g. lid closure or suspend) I will lose connection. That is, i3bar will tell me I'm still connected, and that I still have an IP, but no ping response from any server.

In this state, when I attempt to change wireless connection using `netctl-auto switch-to`, I get

```
WPA association/authentication failed for interface 'wlp58s0'
```

(Obviously all the keys are correct as the connections work at other times.) The only thing that seems to cure this state is a reboot, and it always fixes the problem.

During the reboot I often see this message (see below for `journalctl` output):

```
brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_tx_ioctl: Failed to reserve space in commonring
```

Some details:

```
~$ lspci -vnn | grep -i net
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a3] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0021]

~$ lsmod | grep brcmfmac
brcmfmac              233472  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              516096  1 brcmfmac
mmc_core              122880  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,brcmfmac
usbcore               208896  7 uvcvideo,usbhid,cdc_acm,xhci_pci,brcmfmac,btusb,xhci_hcd

~$ pacman -Q linux
linux 4.13.3-1
```

Fortunately, as I was typing this up it happened again. Here's the output of `journalctl | grep brcmfmac` since I turned the laptop on (cold start) this morning:

```
Sep 29 08:04:09 thelonious kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
Sep 29 08:04:09 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Sep 29 08:04:11 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.txt failed with error -2
Sep 29 08:04:11 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 22 2015 06:16:26 version 7.35.180.119 (r594535) FWID 01-e791c176
Sep 29 08:04:11 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
Sep 29 08:55:42 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_query_dcmd: Timeout on response for query command
Sep 29 08:55:42 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_dump_station: BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported, err=-5
Sep 29 08:55:44 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_query_dcmd: Timeout on response for query command
... snip multiple identical errors ...
Sep 29 08:57:57 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_dump_station: BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported, err=-5
Sep 29 08:57:57 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_tx_ioctl: Failed to reserve space in commonring
Sep 29 08:57:57 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_dump_station: BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported, err=-12
Sep 29 08:58:00 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_tx_ioctl: Failed to reserve space in commonring
... snip multiple identical errors ...
Sep 29 08:58:20 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_tx_ioctl: Failed to reserve space in commonring
Sep 29 08:58:20 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_dump_station: BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported, err=-12
```

Following such a failure of the kernel module, simply restarting the service does not help:

```
~$ sudo systemctl restart netctl-auto@wlp57s0.service
A dependency job for netctl-auto@wlp57s0.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.

~$ sudo journalctl -xe 
Sep 30 10:51:58 thelonious sudo[3626]:    basie : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/basie ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart netctl-auto@wlp5
Sep 30 10:51:58 thelonious sudo[3626]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 30 10:51:58 thelonious systemd[1]: Unnecessary job for sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp57s0.device was removed.
-- Subject: Unit sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp57s0.device has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp57s0.device has failed.
-- 
-- The result is collected.
Sep 30 10:51:58 thelonious systemd[1]: netctl-auto@wlp57s0.service: Bound to unit sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlp57s0.device, but unit isn't acti
Sep 30 10:51:58 thelonious systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Automatic wireless network connection using netctl profiles.
-- Subject: Unit netctl-auto@wlp57s0.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit netctl-auto@wlp57s0.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is dependency.
Sep 30 10:51:58 thelonious systemd[1]: netctl-auto@wlp57s0.service: Job netctl-auto@wlp57s0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 30 10:51:58 thelonious sudo[3626]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Sep 30 10:52:00 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_tx_ioctl: Failed to reserve space in commonring
Sep 30 10:52:00 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_dump_station: BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported, err=-12
...snip identical messages...
Sep 30 10:52:05 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_dump_station: BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported, err=-12
Sep 30 10:52:10 thelonious kernel: net_ratelimit: 2 callbacks suppressed
Sep 30 10:52:10 thelonious kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_tx_ioctl: Failed to reserve space in commonring
...etc...
```

So, two questions:

1. What further steps can I take to diagnose this? Obviously the module
   is receiving a command it doesn't support (I note this patch from
   2015 https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7354871/) but I'm not sure
   where to go from here.
2. What is it about rebooting that solves the
   issue that I could try from a terminal to narrow my search?

Comment: I have the same issue. Let's see if we can figure this out. It happened to me since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 (linux 4.13.0) from 4.4 probably. Need to verify that..

Comment: That would be great. I did wonder if I might ask someone off the kernel maintainers list who might know a bit about Broadcom drivers.

Comment: Of course, it's possible it's just a driver bug in which case a bug report is the obvious next step. But if it's misconfiguration, that would be good to know too.

Comment: I also have this issue on a 2015 Dell XPS 13

Comment: Disabling power management worked to "fix" it for me. See https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201853 I have a systemd unit to do it after networking is up. I can share that if you like

Comment: The command I used to shut it off is `sudo iw dev wlp58s0 set power_save off`. Supposedly this will mean your battery life will suffer but it will probably be negligible if you use the network heavily anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I get the same

> brcmfmac: brcmf_msgbuf_tx_ioctl: Failed to reserve space in commonring

repeatedly on my XPS 15 (9550), when the wifi has dropped, usually after sleep/awake. Usually I can fix it with

> $ sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac ; sudo modprobe brcmfmac

avoiding  reboot.